# Installed colorama module, but PyCharm can't find it

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-module, colorama

Succesfuly installed and upgraded the package, still, PyCharm doesn't recognise:

```
from colorama import fore
```

Error msg: `ImportError: No module named 'colorama'`.

Comment: Have you installed colorama in Python 3.5 interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you installed Colorama, it probably isn't on your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)
environment variable. There are already lots of great answers on this site about how to view/update your PYTHONPATH, so I won't repeat them here.